# trying to Deploying asp.net web api to azure app service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

i am trying to deploy a asp.net core web api to azure app service[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

i try signing in with the account i created on azure but it keeps on bring me to the last step

Comment: What's issue you are having with? Did you created the resource group on azure portal? What's you role there? You should have `administrator` or `contributor` role there.

Comment: You should use `tenant specific account` for example `xxx@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com` with above-described role. [`You check the official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-6.0#deploy-the-app-to-azure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you find that VS always aksed you to sign in, but you've entered the user name and password, then pls close the publish window, and open it again. I faced the same issue before, so it may help you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Thabiso Any progress sir ?